# Application error when drawing to SurfaceView

Tags: android, xml, drawing, surfaceview

I'm am doing a simple coding attempt trying to draw on a SurfaceView created on my main.xml layout. I can change background color and display an icon fine, but when I try to draw I get an error. I am a newbie so obvious I am missing something, please lend a helping hint, thanks!

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/Paper"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </SurfaceView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and code here;

```
package com.example.SurfaceViewTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SurfaceViewTest extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Paint paint;
    Bitmap mDrawing;

    boolean mRun;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.Paper);

        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();

        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 0));
        mRun=true;
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread(){

        public void doDraw(Canvas c){
            mDrawing = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 300, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

            c.setBitmap(mDrawing);

            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255,255));

            c.drawLine(1,1,200,300, paint);
        }

        public void run() {
            while (mRun) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

UPDATE:

Ok I got it to works thanks!

```
package com.example.SurfaceViewTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SurfaceViewTest extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    Bitmap mDrawing;
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas();
    Paint paint;

    boolean mRun;

    int intCanvasWidth, intCanvasHeight;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.Paper);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        intCanvasWidth = width;
        intCanvasHeight = height;
        mDrawing = Bitmap.createBitmap(intCanvasWidth, intCanvasHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (thread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            thread = new Thread();
        }
        mRun = true;
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        mRun = false;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void doDraw(Canvas c) {
            tempCanvas.setBitmap(mDrawing);

            paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255,255));

            tempCanvas.drawLine(1,1,200,300, paint);

            c.drawBitmap(mDrawing, 0, 0, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (mRun) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        doDraw(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how my SurfaceView works. I think your problem is doing your Bitmap in surfaceCreated().

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.start();
}

Thread thread = new Thread(){
...
public void doDraw(Canvas c){
//draw onto the canvas here
}

public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            doDraw(c);
        }
        } finally {
        // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
        // inconsistent state
        if (c != null) {
            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        }
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but there seems to be a bracket missing in new thread. Could you please point out where as I am a newbie with both Android and Java.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If not you really should be. It will point out roughly where the bracket is missing (it's right at the end).

Comment: I am thanks, it's all the way at then end, saying either insert ";" to complete field declaration or "}". Neither removes error.

Comment: Error happens even when I boil it down to this;

Thread thread = new Thread(){

}

Comment: I also updated my code in top question, to reflect the solution you also came up with, plus a need for setting mRun to true, however still getting an error. I can't tell you how much appreciate your help, as once I get beyond this hurdle I can continue playing with graphics

Comment: This code is not complete code, it's merely a guideline! There's a lot of functionality you're going to need to build in before you can start playing with graphics!

Comment: Ok I figured thanks, I been trying to get this to work for more than a week, and will leave question up hoping somebody has time to show me complete example. Thanks again though!

Comment: Ok after I got my Surface view test code to work, I am filling screen with random dots, instead of the line above in my working code. However since your solution was not a class, I am having a hard time figuring out how to stop and restart the thread at will. Setting mRun to false sure stops it, but setting it back to true does not restart it. Any suggestions

Comment: You'll need to set `mRun` to `true` and restart the Thread to get it to run again.

Comment: Yeah tried that too, but it ain't restarting. Thanks though but I will start a new thread, phun intended, for that particular issue.